# How to print a diamond shape composed of letters?

Tags: c#

I want to learn how can I print diamond as follows: I am beginner, so many many thanks for Help

Given a letter print a diamond starting with 'A'
with the supplied letter at the widest point.

For example: print-diamond 'E' prints

```
    A
   B B
  C   C
 D     D
E       E
 D     D
  C   C
   B B
    A
```

For example: print-diamond 'C' prints

```
  A
 B B
C   C
 B B
  A
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the question? You gave us a problem specification with examples and some code, so what is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like homework, and looks like you haven't actually stated what your problem is.

Comment: I suspect something is going wrong with the for-loops referencing the integer `i` on the right side of the condition parts.

Comment: @Mashton: Being homework isn't, in and of itself a problem. And the OP clearly has some code so they look like they've made an effort. The not stating the problem is the problem. Does the code even work? If not, what's it doing that isn't right?

Comment: //construct diamond,it give compilation error "use of unassigned local variable ' letter_number' " 

            for (int i = 0; i < letter_number + i; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Tested working.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] letter = new char[26]
            {
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',
                'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
            };
            int letter_number = 0;

            //array of strings
            string[] diamond = new string[52];
            //get the letter
            Console.WriteLine("User enters a Letter between A and Z ");
            char user_letter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            //search for letter number in the array letter
            for (int i = 0; i < letter.Length; i++)
            {
                if (letter[i] == user_letter)
                {
                    letter_number = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //construct diamond 

            for (int i = 0; i <= letter_number; i++)
            {
                //add initial spaces
                for (int j = 0; j < letter_number - i; j++)
                {
                    diamond[i] += " ";
                }

                //add letter (first time)
                diamond[i] += letter[i];

                //add space between letters
                if (letter[i] != 'A')
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2*i - 1; j++)
                    {
                        diamond[i] += " ";
                    }
                    //add letter (second time)
                    diamond[i] += letter[i];
                }
                // Draw the first part of the diamond as it's composing.
                Console.WriteLine(diamond[i]);
            }

            for (int i = letter_number - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // Draw the second part of the diamond
                // Writing the diamondArray in reverse order.
                Console.WriteLine(diamond[i]);
            }

            // Mark a pause
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
User enters a Letter between A and Z
K
          A
         B B
        C   C
       D     D
      E       E
     F         F
    G           G
   H             H
  I               I
 J                 J
K                   K
 J                 J
  I               I
   H             H
    G           G
     F         F
      E       E
       D     D
        C   C
         B B
          A
```

Comment: is there a way to unit test the above program? thanks

Comment: You mean mesure the working time to print the array depending of the key ?

Comment: like testing the result is correct against user input as in your example above user input is K and result is correct , how to do that in unit test in this simple program as Mr. Andy mentioned.

Comment: I think you should open a new SO thread with this specific questions : "How to unit test for correct result the following program ?" then paste the code I gave you and its correct output. Also, make yourself a reflexion about what's an incorrect result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code has two errors (I'm not considering efficiency of your code and algorhims).

**First:** when you are constructing diamond, for-loop should be not `for (int i = 0; i < letter_number + i; i++)` but `for (int i = 0; i <= letter_number; i++)`.

**Second:** when you are drawing diamond - variable `j` should be placed out of loop, and you should use `WriteLine` instead of `Write`.

For example, drawing part of your code can be something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine();
int jj = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * letter_number + 1; i++)
{
    if (i < letter_number + 1)
        Console.WriteLine(diamond[i]);
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(diamond[i - 2 * jj]);
        jj++;
    }
}
```

**Side note:** `int letter_number;` should be initialized as `int letter_number = 0;` or something like this, because you are assigning it's value under condition and not in every case later in the code, and actually code you've provided even don't compile without this explicit initialization.

Comment: @ Andy , Thank you very much for your help ,really appreciate. I can see how fool and behind  I am in programming. I will be grateful for your help to guide how can I unit test this above program.

Comment: Nice of you all, I understand your insight regarding unit testing. I was thinking if I want to unit test this ,is it possible . I added test project to the solution Nunit and reference to the main project . public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

           

        }
    }