# Upside down pyramid

Tags: c#

How can I make this diamond-shaped patter using c#?

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * * 
    *
```

Below code will generate the upper side of pattern.

Is it possible to create the lower side pattern in the same loop?

```
void create()
{
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var k = 0;

    var num = 5;
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < num - i + 1; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexei Is it possible to create this shape in the same for loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280461/477420 shows how to combine both loops into one. I'm not exactly sure why that is not enough for "yes". (BTW, asking "yes or no" question is generally too broad... maybe that was better close reason)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This will not solve my problem. Two loops are there to create the upper and lower part of the diamond.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am very much new to StackOverflow as you can see my reputation. Regarding "yes or no" I am still learning the art of asking questions. Thanks

Comment: Why do you care how many loops are used? Is this some coding challenge?

Comment: P.s. read the specific answer which alexei linked to in his last comment. It definitely only uses one loop

Answer (score 0):

void create()
{

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;

var num = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < num - i + 1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

}
for (i = (num-1); i > 0; i--)
{
    for (j = 1; j < num - i + 1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

}
```

}